# Scheduled, bulk reverse image search tool

Tags: images

I used to use a service called Image Raider, which allowed me to upload a library of images and once a month it would run a batch google reverse image search to find all the sites that had published my images.

Unfortunately Image Raider is no more, and the only alternative i can find is Tiny Eye who charge >$300 per month for a similar service, where as i was paying about $100 per year for Image Raider.

Dose anyone know of any other similar tools ?

Comment: Your question does not mention scheduling, only the title does, so you might want to change it. Windows, Linux & Mac all allow you to schedule things, so bet to concentrate on reverse image search.